# Custom Health Indicator for multiple instances of a Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, cloud-foundry, spring-reactive, health-check

I have a Spring Boot (2.3.3) application which is deployed on PCF and it has 5 instances running.

For monitoring the health of this application, I added the custom health indicator where I implemented/override the ReactiveHealthIndicator of actuator package. The health() method calls a session service to tell that whether an instance is up or down after certain count.

The issue is that, even if one instance is going down, the PCF healthcheck bring down all the instances and restarts.

How I can make sure that the PCF healthcheck restart only those instance which is down and not all the instances.

My custom health indicator:

```
    @Component @Slf4j @ConditionalOnProperty(
            value = "app.custom.health.enabled",
            havingValue = "true",
            matchIfMissing = true) 
public class MyCustomHealthIndicator implements ReactiveHealthIndicator {
    
        private MyAsyncSessionHealthCheck myAsyncSessionHealthCheck;
    
        public MyCustomHealthIndicator(MyAsyncSessionHealthCheck myAsyncSessionHealthCheck) {
            this.myAsyncSessionHealthCheck = myAsyncSessionHealthCheck;
            log.info("Using Custom health indicator.");
        }
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Health> health() {
            Health health = Health.up().build();
    
            // Fire and forget async health check on session
            myAsyncSessionHealthCheck.checkSessionHealth();
    
            // Check counter and fail if greater than max
            if (myAsyncSessionHealthCheck.checkForSessionFailure()) {
                log.error("Health Down because of session service check failed.");
                health = Health.down().withDetail("REASON", "Session service failed.").build();
            }
            return Mono.just(health);
        } }
```

Comment: The platform health check is unique to an instance. It happens inside the application's container, so if an individual instance's health check passes, then that instance will stay up. If it fails, then only that instance will go down.

Comment: Can you expand on what your customizing with your custom health check? Or link to sample code for it?

Comment: Thanks @DanielMikusa for looking into this. I added my sample code for health indicator in my question section.

Comment: Can I configure the PCF Healthcheck to change this behavior?

Comment: There is no way to change the platform behavior. I do not think you'd want to if you could. I suspect what's happening is that your call to the service is failing, it's external so if that fails then all of your app instances are going to fail their health check. Maybe that's what you want? maybe not. Its hard to say with the info provided.

Comment: Thanks, for the valuable feedback. I will work on some other approach. Your information was helpful to understand the situation better.